# HA Singleton not working in Wildfly 8

Tags: wildfly-8

Could anyone provide a working example of HA Singleton implementation for Wildfly 8? I have tried a couple of things including [this](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/cluster-ha-singleton).

However it always started multiple instances on various cluster nodes/servers. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Think you are referring to this 
https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/8.x/cluster-ha-singleton

I am able to run this as a standalone HA implementation on my local.
however while deploying it in domain mode to other environments with multiple applications using similar logic having issues with infinispan cache